# Need to insert a button in header area for avada theme

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a button in the header area in avada theme , WordPress. I am new to WordPress and couldn't find the right place in header.php to do this. I tried searching for  in header.php , but not finding this line of code in it as well.

Please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might help if you post some code, what you have already tried that is not working will assist people to provide you help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this in the header.php file,  you can do it from the Wordpress administration instead.

Select Appearance > Menus > Custom Links.  Make sure you select the "Main Navigation" in the menu to edit at the top.

In Custom Links populate the URL and Link Text and click "Add to Menu" and this will create a link in the menu.  Once the link is on the right,  click the carrot next to "Custom Link" and change the Menu First Level Style to "Button".

Answer (score -1):

This is the best solution. Use the Header that has the option for tag line:
Yes, create a button in a draft page, then grab the code from editor and paste it in header section where the tag line would go.